# How to restart my application if Windows Update forces a reboot?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, windows-update

At the office, when I leave for the night I very rarely log off or reboot.  I simply lock my workstation and go home, leaving all my development tools exactly how I left them.

If Windows-Update rolls through and reboots my machine in the middle of the night I'm only slightly peeved because when I log back in the next morning, any MS Office application, or Visual Studio instance I had running will have already automatically restarted, opening whatever file(s)/projects/solutions I may have been working on.

**My question is:** How can I make my Windows Forms applications (C#) do this?  Is there some way for my application to "register" that it wants to be restarted if the system automatically reboots?

Comment: I would like to know that for WPF applications as well. One would expect this would be independent of GUI framework.

Comment: have you tried putting the executable in the startup?

Comment: @birdlips: That is not the desired behavior.  I do not want my application *always* starting when Windows starts.  Only if it was running when Windows Update shutdown Windows.

Comment: I would assume Office and VS are restarted with no need to put them in startup. (Putting Office in Startup? Ewwwww!)

Comment: In think that both Office and Visual Studio use the restart and recovery API (although maybe the native one, not the managed one). I just heard about it on a .NET Rocks episode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I *think* the [RegisterApplicationRestart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373347(VS.85).aspx) Win32 API function might be what you're after, it's part of the Restart Manager API.

Comment: Note that the minimum supported client platform is Windows Vista.

Comment: This apears to be for C++. There is now a managed restart and recovery api.

Comment: @Jacob - umm, yup - hence me saying it's a Win32 function, there's nothing to stop the OP making a PInvoke call though =)

Answer (score 4):

If you have Windows Vista or Windows 7, you can use the Managed Restart and Recovery API. The links on that page also point to some useful blog entries

http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/DanielMoth/Windows-Vista-Restart-amp-Recovery-APIs-from-managed-code/

Comment: A small point (having just re-read Daniel Moth's blog entries, I remember reading them when originally published now!) - there's not actually a Managed API, what DM demonstrates is how to call the WIn32 API from managed code =)

Comment: Good video link.  But it doesn't answer the question: I want my application to restart upon Windows restart when it's forced to close because Windows Update is forcing a restart of Windows, not when my application fails in a firey ball of crashy flames.

Comment: I think it does answer your question. I think the function will be called in either case.  Here is the link to the .NET Rocks transcripts that seems to indicate it.  Search for "restart" around page 7
http://perseus.franklins.net/dotnetrocks_0443_kate_gregory.pdf

Comment: Hmmm, yes, they do start talking about it on page 7 of the transcript, and what Kate Gregory is saying makes it sound like it can do exactly what I'm looking for.  

It wasn't until just now that I realized that this is going to be a major pain to test. ;)  I'm going to have fire up some non-updated VM I think...

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to add an entry to the following registry key :

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
```

Just create a value containing the path of your app (optionally including command line arguments). The app will be run at the next startup, then the value will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Figure out a way to differentiate a windows-triggered restart from a standard one.  One solution would be to try preprocessing [messages](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/10/20/245412.aspx).  They're probably different for a windows-triggered restart...or at least they are in Vista in some cases :/

Step 2: If you detect it's a windows-triggered restart, add a scheduled, one-time task.